# How to modify the operating system user of existing SequoiaDB cluster?

Tags: database, sequoiadb

Assume that the operating system user of the SequoiaDB cluster is sdbadmin and the user group is sdbadmin_group. Now I want to modify the user of the SequoiaDB cluster from sdbadmin to sdb, and the user group from sdbadmin_group to sdb. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the original installation directory is: /opt/sequoiadb
1. Create new users and user groups in Linux.

2. Stop the entire cluster (including the sdbcm/sdbcmd/sdbom process).
3. Modify the permissions of all files and data directories of the cluster in batches.
4. Replace the new user to /etc/default/sequoiadb.
5. Change the user group of /opt/sequoiadb/uninstall to: "root:root".
6. Give /opt/sequoiadb/bin/sdbomtool the suid permission for the root user. The steps are as follows:
        1) su - root
        2) chown root:root /opt/sequoiadb/bin/sdbomtool
        3) chmod 6755 /opt/sequoiadb/bin/sdbomtool

Note: After replacing a user, you need to ensure that the directory (including executables, data, log directories) can be used by new users.